# How do I pass a pre-constructed instance to a provider in guice?

Tags: guice, provider

I understand that if we need to tell guice that we need a specific instance bound to a type, we use the provider interface a to return a newly constructed object...so provider acts like a factory.

In all the examples I have seen the provder itself figures out what to return based on some information from compile time.

How do I pass the provider an object that is created by some other means out of my control ?

--Edit: Is below modification of Olivier's first solution an acceptable usage pattern ?

```
public class FrameworkModule extends AbstractModule {

  private static instance; 
  public FrameworkModule(FrameworkImplementation instanceCreatedbyFramework) {
     instance=instanceCreatedbyFramework;
  }

  protected void configure() {}

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  FrameworkInterface provideFrameworkInterface() { //this method does not have information to create and in initialize instance. The Framework get initialized first and already creates the instance object. I have the ability to construct guice bindings module after framework is initialized
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: As I mentioned- it is outside of my control. All code cannot be written ground up with guice. This is an existing class and a singleton object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do so.

Using provide method

```
public class FrameworkModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {}

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  FrameworkInterface provideFrameworkInterface() {
    FrameworkImplementation instance = Framework.newInstance();
    instance.initialize();
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Using standard declaration

```
public class FrameworkModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    FrameworkImplementation instance = Framework.newInstance();
    instance.initialize();
    bind(FrameworkInterface.class).toInstance(instance);
  }
}
```

Using providers:

```
public class FrameworkModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    FrameworkImplementation instance = Framework.newInstance();
    Provider<FrameworkInterface> provider = () -> instance;
    bind(FrameworkInterface.class).toProvider(provider);
  }
}
```

The thing is that your question is maybe too vague and if this answer doesn't help, please refine your question so I can edit this answer.

Comment: `toInstance(...).in(...);` is redundant, and actually won't compile, as `toInstance()` returns `void`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes You're right. I made several copy/pastes before getting to those answers and messed the result a bit. I fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Thankyou Olivier. Looks like I can use a variation of your solution #1. I cannot do this specifically Framework.newInstance(); But I think I can initialize FrameworkModule with instance and just return that with the provides....